# How do I pass arguments to delegates?

Tags: c#, events

I have the following pseudo code that works:

```
KeyBindings[Keys.Right] += Method1;
KeyBindings[Keys.Right] += Method2;
```

The problem I'm running into is that I would like to be able to do this:

```
KeyBindings[Keys.Right] += Method1(argument);
KeyBindings[Keys.Right] += Method2(argument1, argument 2);
```

Is this possible? If so, how do I rewrite my code to achieve this?

---

KeyBindings is defined as:

```
Dictionary<Keys, Action> KeyBindings = new Dictionary<Keys, Action>();
```

Comment: What is `KeyBindings` supposed to be?  A dictionary of delegates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Dictionary<ConsoleKey, Action> KeyBindings = new Dictionary<ConsoleKey, Action>();
        KeyBindings[ConsoleKey.A] = null;
        KeyBindings[ConsoleKey.A] += () => Method1(12);
    }

    static void Method1(int arg) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I haven't seen Kittoes' update until after I made that comment.  Your code is actually fine just the way it was since we actually know what the type is now, the compiler can infer what type the lambda is.

Comment: @Dmitry Nogin: I tried to comment on this earlier but it said the post no longer exists and I was quite sad. This worked flawlessly but my problem with it is that I don't understand why. Do you happen to have a solid link where I can really pick up on lambda expressions in C#?

Comment: You might have a look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24255/Exploring-Lambda-Expression-in-C

Answer (score 3):

Well in general, if you wanted to create a delegate that would take some existing function and apply a preset set of arguments, you would need to wrap the function inside another.

e.g.,

Consider function `Foo()` that takes one `string` argument and returns an `int` (which has the same signature as `Func<string, int>`):

```
int Foo(string str)
{
    return str.Length + 8941;
}
```

If you wanted to use this to create a delegate that returns the result of calling `Foo` of the string `"bar"`, you could do this:

```
Func<int> foobar = () => Foo("bar");
```

So notice that we created a new delegate, the lambda expression that takes nothing and (in this case) returns the result of calling `Foo("bar")`.

---

You can apply the same thing in your code:

```
KeyBindings[Keys.Right] += new Action(() => Method1(argument));
KeyBindings[Keys.Right] += new Action(() => Method2(argument1, argument 2));
```

Comment: **KeyBindings[Keys.Right] += () => Actions.MoveRight(arg1, arg2);** works perfectly. I was commenting on the first dude who suggested it but he appears to have removed his answer.

Comment: @Kittoes: Yeah, it was impossible to tell if that would have worked since we (initially) didn't know what types we were dealing with here. But since you've added that in, it would indeed work just like that. Based on what you had originally shown, it implied `Method1()` and `Method2()` were different types therefore the dictionary had to store `Delegate` rather than a specific type such as `Action`.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: Your post was helpful and enlightening nonetheless. Thanks much. Do you have a solid link where I can really learn/come to understand this lambda nonsense?

Comment: @Kittoes: The lambda (`blah => blah`) is just a construct to quickly define inline methods. It's roughly the same as if you used the older syntax of defining anonymous methods: `delegate (SomeType someArg) { return someValue; }`. If you can understand how those work, you can understand lambdas. Just think of it as a method body that you don't need to name and put into a class. (There's more to it than that such as scoping and it's a closure but you'll learn about that the more you use them) I don't have any links on hand, but I'd just advise you to keep using them and it'll come to you.

Comment: @JeffMercado: So... are you saying that they're more or less syntactical sugar? Behind the scenes the compiler is creating delegates for me? Is there any type of performance hit/resource cost for writing things this way? I've only been coding in C# for about a month now so I'm still really shaky on a bunch of things.

Comment: @Kittoes: Yep you hit is on the head. I'm not aware of any performance differences, they all feel the same to me compared to actual named methods.  Others would suggest that there is a slight performance penalty if I'm not mistaken.  But it's not something to be concerned about.  It's just a function and that's all you really need to know.

Comment: @JeffMercado: I ran into a problem with some testing using the lambda functions I wrote out last night. Any way you could help me out in chat for a few min?

Comment: @Kittoes: Not at this moment right now sorry, work, I can probably be available to you in another 40 minutes (00:30 UTC).

Comment: @JeffMercado: I got time all day/night. Whatever works for you. I browse around here a lot so you can post a comment or send me a text @ 626-KITTOES whenever you get some spare time.

Comment: @Kittoes: It turns out I may not be able to chat with you today, things came up at work which took up all my time. I won't be available until late at night for me so that's a no go. I would be available at around this time tomorrow though (01:40 UTC).

Comment: @JeffMercado: Not a problem. I got plenty of other crazy things to do/learn with this project.

Comment: @Kittoes: I should be available for the weekend so if you have the time, invite me to a chatroom or something when you're ready.  I should be near my computer and check the sites regularly. I might not be able to stop and chat with you in realtime but could still respond without too much delay.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Thanks. I'm back at work for the night so whenever you get a chance...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way.  You are not calling a method at this point... you are simply telling it which method it should use.

When you create an event, you specify what kind of method it takes which includes the parameters.  The parameters are passed at the place where the event is raised.

Here is a tutorial on the subject that will help you understand better:
http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson14.aspx

Looking at the code below may also help you put the pieces together a little better.

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    //Assign the delegate
    KeyBindings[Keys.Right] += Method1;
}

public PlaceWhereEventGetsRaised()
{
    object argument1, argument2;

    // set the arguments to something

    if (KeyBindings[Keys.Right] != null) 
        KeyBindings[Keys.Right](argument1, argument2);
}

public void Method1(object argument1, object argument2)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

If it looks like you are unable to accomplish what you were wanting to do the way you thought, then let us know what you're trying to do and maybe we can help you find the right approach.

Comment: I was afraid of that since I've been at this a while with no luck. Is there any way I can rewrite this to get the functionality that I desire?

Comment: Can you explain what the functionality you're looking for should do?  The more specific you can be about your actual problem the better.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm trying to pass known variables to known functions. I have a static class of functions like Move() and Animate() that I would like to pass parameters to. With my current implementation I'm forced to pass those parameters where the event is fired and it just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Kittoes It might make more sense to create a separate class to encapsulate those variables and another collection class (possibly static or singleton) to manage them.  Then when you know the values you can store them in the class, and when the events are fired the methods that need them can look them up.  Your code would probably be simpler to write and maintain this way.  Or maybe there is only one set of variables and you just need one static class to store them in?

Answer (score 0):

To do such thing you have to create new method that has those args fixed inside. Or anonymus method like this:

```
event += (s, someEventArgs) => Method1(s, someEventArgs, someOtherArgs)
```